# Python translation from C for CS50 greedy algorithm

Tags: python, greedy

So, we all know that CS50 is a big class and lots to learn. Here's another issue I'm having with Python now. The syntax took a little while to get right with all the indentation changes but the logic seems to be very similar. The code works up until you put in .99 or even 1.20. BUT, and it's a big but, I can't debug in the cloud9 ide with Python.....? Idk. I just started Python this week so I'm sure it's a language oriented issue and I just need to figure that out. Hope you can help me. Thanks.

```
#Greedy algorithm converted to python
import sys
import os

c = float(input("How much change is owed? "))
i = 0
while (c<0 or c==0):
    print("Please input a positive amount...")

while (c>.24):

    i  += 1
    c=(c-.25)

while (c>.1 or c==.1):

    i += 1
    c=(c-.1)


while (c>.05 or c==.05):

    i += 1
    c=(c-.05)


while (c>.01 or c==.01):

    i += 1
    c=(c-.01)

print("%i coin(s) needed to make the change." % i)
```

Comment: A couple outcomes are as follows:
1.2 gives me 10 coins
.99 gives me 8 coins
.5 gives me 2 coins
1 gives me 4 coins
.95 gives me 9 coins

Comment: It's probably worth noting that it's almost always a bad idea to use floating point numbers to represent dollar amounts. When you type `0.01`, that number is actually stored as `0.01000000000000000020816681711721685132943093776702880859375` because 1/100 is not exactly representable as a sum of powers of two.

Comment: Here's a StackExchange site, dedicated to CS50: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So don't use float...but int didn't work at all at first. Is there a double? Or decimal in python?

Comment: There is indeed a Decimal type in Python, available in the standard `decimal` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely running into rounding issues with `float`. After converting it to cents and using integers, it works:

```
#Greedy algorithm converted to python
import sys
import os

c = float(input("How much change is owed? "))
i = 0
while (c<0 or c==0):
    print("Please input a positive amount...")
c = round(c * 100)
while (c>=25):

    i  += 1
    c=(c-25)

while (c>=10):

    i += 1
    c=(c-10)


while (c>=5):

    i += 1
    c=(c-5)


while (c>=1):

    i += 1
    c=(c-1)

print("%i coin(s) needed to make the change." % i)
```

Comment: I see. That would work but, I'd like to keep it cleaner. I've been looking but I couldn't find a format for a decimal to 2 places. Would that help even if I did?

Comment: format for decimal to 2 places? Not sure what that means, but note that `round(cent * 100)` converts it to cents and rounds it to the nearest integer, so if you were to input 0.256, it would be 26 cents, which is what you want.

Comment: Allow me to reiterate; when I get the input from user as a float, can I then 'format' that float to 2 decimal places (ie. .99 instead of .993321004) and then have that formatting throughout the program? I understand that ("{:.1f}".format(c)) changes the variable to a string so I can't use that it seems.

Comment: You can do that by doing `round(c, 2)`, but the result is going to be a float, whether it's 0.2560000000001 or 0.2600000001.

Answer (score 0):

**My C# implementation seems off but look below for it's python implementation.
Using cs50's header file.**

````
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int greedyAlgorithm(float change);

//main
int main(void)
{
    float change;
    do
    {
        printf("What is the change owed\n");
        change = get_float("$: ");
    }while(change<0);
    greedyAlgorithm(change);
}

//greedyAlgorithm implementation
int greedyAlgorithm(float change)
{
    int coins[4] = {25, 10, 5, 1};
    int amount, totalCoins, tmpNumber, remainder, quarterCounter, dimeCounter, nickelCounter, pennyCounter;
    amount = round(change * 100);
    tmpNumber = 0;
    remainder = 0;
    totalCoins = 0;
    quarterCounter =0;
    dimeCounter = 0;
    nickelCounter = 0;
    pennyCounter = 0;
    
    if (amount >= coins[0])//quarter
    {
        remainder = amount % coins[0];
        tmpNumber = amount - remainder;
        totalCoins = totalCoins + (tmpNumber / coins[0]);
        quarterCounter = tmpNumber / coins[0];
        amount = remainder;
        printf("Quarters: %i\n", quarterCounter);
    }
        if (amount >= coins[1])//dime
    {
        remainder = amount % coins[1];
        tmpNumber = amount - remainder;
        totalCoins = totalCoins + (tmpNumber / coins[1]);
        dimeCounter = tmpNumber / coins[1];
        amount = remainder;
        printf("Dimes: %i\n", dimeCounter);
    }
        if (amount >= coins[2])//nickle
    {
        remainder = amount % coins[2];
        tmpNumber = amount - remainder;
        totalCoins = totalCoins + (tmpNumber / coins[2]);
        nickelCounter = tmpNumber / coins[2];
        amount = remainder;
        printf("Nickels: %i\n", nickelCounter);
    }
        if (amount >= coins[3])//penny
    {
        remainder = amount % coins[3];
        tmpNumber = amount - remainder;
        totalCoins = totalCoins + (tmpNumber / coins[3]);
        pennyCounter = tmpNumber / coins[3];
        amount = remainder;
        printf("Pennies: %i\n", pennyCounter);
    }
    printf("Total Coins: %i\n", totalCoins);
    return 0;
}```
**Python equivalent**
#get user input
import math


def greedyAlgorithm(change):
    coins = [25, 10, 5, 1] #coins denominations
    tmpNumber = 0
    remainder = 0
    totalCoins = 0
    quarterCounter =0
    dimeCounter = 0
    nickelCounter = 0
    pennyCounter = 0
    amount = round(int(change*100))
    if amount >= coins[0]: #quarter
        remainder = amount % coins[0]
        tmpNumber = amount - remainder
        totalCoins = totalCoins + (tmpNumber / coins[0])
        quarterCounter = tmpNumber / coins[0]
        amount = remainder
        print(f"Quarters:  {int(quarterCounter)}")
    
    if amount >= coins[1]: #dime
    
        remainder = amount % coins[1]
        tmpNumber = amount - remainder
        totalCoins = totalCoins + (tmpNumber / coins[1])
        dimeCounter = tmpNumber / coins[1]
        amount = remainder
        print(f"Dimes:  {int(dimeCounter)}")
    
    if amount >= coins[2]: #nickle
    
        remainder = amount % coins[2]
        tmpNumber = amount - remainder
        totalCoins = totalCoins + (tmpNumber / coins[2])
        nickelCounter = tmpNumber / coins[2]
        amount = remainder
        print(f"Nickels:  {int(nickelCounter)}")
    
    if amount >= coins[3]:#penny
    
        remainder = amount % coins[3]
        tmpNumber = amount - remainder
        totalCoins = totalCoins + (tmpNumber / coins[3])
        pennyCounter = tmpNumber / coins[3]
        amount = remainder
        print(f"Pennies: {int(pennyCounter)}")
    print(f"Total Coins: {int(totalCoins)}")
    
            
print("What is the change owed")
print("$: ", end="")
change = float(input())
greedyAlgorithm(change)
````